# How to stop a code when a counter reaches a certain number

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set up a code where you can click a button and every time you click the button it adds "one" to the counter. Then I want the code to stop when the counter reaches a certain number, in this case 5. For some I can't get the stopping part of the code to work. How do I get the if statement working so that the code will stop when the counter reaches that number?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Counter</title>
 </head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };


      if (clicks < 5) {
  continue;
} else {
  break;
}
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put the check inside the `onClick` function, and if it fails, `return`

Comment: I wouldn't call your function onClick() just because that is a property of the button, call it something like, addOne(), just for readability

Comment: Your `if` code runs exactly once, when the page is loaded, then never again. So it never does anything because when it runs, `clicks` is always `0`. `continue` and `break` are used inside blocks to skip the current iteration / exit the block. You need to check the value of `click` inside your click handler function: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qnt538fu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the condition inside the `onClick` method, when the condition meet, you can just `return` from the function without executing the next code, like this:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick()
{
    if (clicks >= 5)
        return;

    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
  if(clicks < 5) {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button when the counter reaches 5

```js
var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
         if (clicks == 5) {
      document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
}
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Counter</title>
 </head>

<body>
    
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Or we can remove the function call all-together.

Here after the click has reached 5 we remove the onclick function call from the button.

```js
    var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        
      if (clicks == 5) {
      document.getElementById("button").removeAttribute("onclick");
      }
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Counter</title>
 </head>

<body>
   
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`continue` and `break` is normally used when you are in a `loop`. Here by `continue` and `break` you can not continue/break anything. Every time button is clicked the function will be called. You can check if `clicks` is less then or equal to `5` by `if` statement and then do something. Try This:

```js
var clicks = 0;
onClick = function() {
  if(clicks <= 5) {
    clicks++;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  }
  /* else {
    clicks = 0;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
  } */
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you did not put the "check" (the `if` statement) inside of your `onClick` function. So, the `if` block would run only once (when the page is loaded), which is obviously not what you want.

I wrote a minimal example similar to what I think you were trying to do; I hope this helps:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
        <button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click Me</button>

        <script>
var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    if(clicks < 5) { clicks++; }
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, your usage of `continue` and `break` is a little misplaced. These are generally used in loops.

**break:** When a break statement is executed, the loop is immediately jumped out of.

**continue**: When a continue statement is executed, the remaining loop code is not run, but the loop is continued (and in a `for` loop, the increment condition will also be run.)

You can read about continue and break [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)